# C++ Hex search in std:string failed

Tags: c++, string, stl, hex, design-patterns

I have an std:string. I would like to find the pattern "0x789c" in hexadecimal.
According another thread in stackoverflow, i have done this :

```
int nPosD = buffer.find("\x78\x9C");
```

and tried

```
int nPosD = buffer.find(std::string("\x78\x9C"),2);
```

No success !The return is  -1 !My pattern 0x789c is in my string ! I have tested it with HexEdit software.

Anyone have idea for this ?

Thanks a lot :)

best regards,

Comment: 0x789c is 0x9c 0x78 in intel processors, not 0x78 0x9c

Comment: Should work, are you sure your hex editing software doesn't show your bytes in little endian (reverse byte order)?

Comment: Your first mistake is to write a binary buffer to a string. A `std::string`’s purpose is to store *text*. If you have binary data, use a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Yes, it was a little endian view in my Hex Editor !! Thanks Joachim Isaksson !

Answer (score 1):

```
int nPosD = buffer.find(std::string("\x78\x9C"),2);
```

will look for the string "\x78\x9c" starting at the 3rd character (offset 2) in buffer.  If it does not appear at or after that point, it will return -1.  If you want to search the entire string from the beginning, get rid of the `2`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
char data[] = {'A', 0x78, 0x9C};
string buffer(data, 3);
cout << buffer.find("\x78\x9C") << endl;
```

It prints "1" as it should. It works as well without the initial A. You have probably set your string wrong. It may contain '0x789c' in ascii instead of binary, in which case you want to do `find("0x789c")`.

Comment: Yes, it was a little endian view in my Hex Editor !! Thanks Joachim Isaksson !